# How to display table of html format on the detail page of an object using apex. I am not using vf page here. Only the controller apex class

Tags: apex, table

Background:
I am trying to reproduce the duplicate records message using apex. As duplication rules is not enabled for person accounts. when i am trying to insert a new person account, I am abe to get the existing duplicate records details in a list. I am trying to construct a table using html displaying each duplicate record in each row. I have this table stored in a string variable. When I do system.debug I am able to print this table with record details but when I am trying to display this table on the person account detail page using return statement. I am not able to succeed. It does not give me any error but also not display anthing on the page.

I am assuming that it is not able to understand the constructed table hence the issue but not aware how to fix this.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: If you want to have the error message displayed on the page when you save the record, you need to use the `addError()` method on the record in the trigger. And I don't believe that there is a way to have the table markup interpreted as html.

Comment: Hi martin.. thanks for the reply.. I have used add error but its not displaying as a table. Instead it is displaying with html tags as a string like - <html> <table> <tr> <td> my duplicate record field 1 <\td> <\tr> < \table> <\html> .. something like this. But not as a table with columns and rows. Also i need the first column of this table to have link to open the detailed page of that record. I used account.adderror(htmltable) .. htmltable is the string which has table constructed

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Post your code so that other members can understand easily

Comment: You are aware of this page? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult.htm Just out of curiosity: why are you using HTML and not Visualforce?